Is pre-unitary operator on Hilbert space unitary?
Ramakrishnan and Valenza define a pre-unitary operator on a pre-Hilbert space to be an operator that preserves the Hermitian form or, equivalently, that $T^*T=1$. (They actually write $TT^*=1$ but I believe this to be wrong.) Afterwards, they claim that "[a] pre-unitary endomorphism on a Hilbert space is, of course, a unitary operator in the usual sense." (p. 73) In Wikipedia, it is stated that a unitary operator should also be surjective. This makes me suspicious of Ramakrishnan and Valenza's definition. I would be grateful if someone could make the situation clear for me.

$T^{*}T=I$ for the right-shift on $\ell^{2}$ and this is not surjective.

@geetha290krm Thank you. And am I correct that preserving Hermitian form is actually equivalent to $T^*T=I$?

Yes, that is correct.
